# Trouble understanding Joint Probability Density for Discrete Random Variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble with understanding this topic. Here's 3 extracts from my book:[image]

[image]

[image]

Does it mean that $P(X =x, Y = y) = p_{X}(x) \cdot P_{Y} (y)?$ Because, isn't this when the 2 R.V are independent? Also, from Definition 3.7.2 above, is $p_X(x) $ and it's $y$ counterpart a marginal pdf? If you could explain it in simpler terms, it would mean a lot since the notations throw me off.

Thanks

Comment: $P(X =x, Y = y) = p_{X}(x) \cdot p_{Y} (y)?$ for all $x,y$ iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent. So the equation does not hold in general. Yes, $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are the marginals.

Comment: Ah ok, but how do you find $(=,=)$ if it's not independent?

Comment: You cannot find it from the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ alone. Some additional information (like how $X$ and $Y$ depend on each other) is needed.

Comment: Thanks! is $p_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)$ one of them? The textbook used $f$ instead of $p$ though, so I'm not sure if it's correct?

Comment: That formula is only for continuous r.v.'s with a density (in which case $p_{X,Y}$ actually stands for the joint density). It does not apply to discrete r.v.'s.